# Applying jQuery to multiple different dynamically created HTML elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form i will be using to edit data in my database. It has 3  which consists of Category,Subcategory and item.The  are dynamically populated based on the value selected in the previous dropdown.After all 3 dropdowns are selected, the current data on the selected item will then be added into the form via jQuery's .load method.

While i currently am able to display the existing data without a problem, the data which is added to the form do not respond to my jQuery code. I suspect this is because the jQuery is inside $(document).ready and as such, runs before the items are added.

If so, what can i do to make the dynamically added parts function with my jQuery?

My jQuery code:

```
// Shows the details when yes is clicked
$('#BizEditItemRadioYes').click(function(){

    $('.BizEdititemDiscountDetails').show();

});
// Hides the details when no is clicked
$('#BizEditItemRadioNo').click(function(){

    $('.BizEdititemDiscountDetails').hide();

});
// calculates the discounted price when discount is checked yes
$('#BizEditItemRadioYes').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Yes'){

    // calculates discount price when discount percentage changes
    $('#BizEditItemPercent').change(function(){
        var percent=$('#BizEditItemPercent').val();
        var price=$('#BizEditItemPrice').val();
        var discountpercent=percent / 100;
        var discountprice=price * discountpercent;
        $('#BizEditItemDiscountPrice').val(price - discountprice);
    });
    // calculates discount price when discount price changes
    $('#BizEditItemPrice').change(function(){
        var percent=$('#BizEditItemPercent').val();
        var price=$('#BizEditItemPrice').val();
        var discountpercent=percent / 100;
        var discountprice=price * discountpercent;
        $('#BizEditItemDiscountPrice').val(price - discountprice);
    });

   }
});
```

Dynamically added content:

```php
echo"<div class='BizEditItemDetails'>";
            echo"<label for='BizEditItemName'>Name:</label>";
            echo"<input class='BizEditItemInput' type='text' id='BizEditItemName' name='BizEditItemName' size='30' maxlength='50' value=\"$name\">";
            echo"<span></span>";
        echo"</div>";

        echo"<div class='BizEditItemDetails'>";
            echo"<label for='BizEditItemPrice'>Price:</label>";
            echo"<input class='BizEditItemInput' type='number' id='BizEditItemPrice' name='BizEditItemPrice' step='any' min=0 value=\"$price\">";
            echo"<span></span>";
        echo"</div>";

        echo"<div class='BizEditItemDetails'>";
            echo"<label>Discount:</label>";
                echo"<input type='radio' class='BizEditItemInput' value='Yes' id='BizEditItemRadioYes' name='BizEditItemDiscount'>Yes";
                echo"<input type='radio' checked='checked' class='BizEditItemInput' value='No'  id='BizEditItemRadioNo' name='BizEditItemDiscount' step='any'>No";
            echo"</span></span>";
        echo"</div>";


        echo"<div class='BizEditItemDetails'>";
            echo"<div class='BizEdititemDiscountDetails'>";
                echo"<label for='BizEditItemPercent'>Discount Percentage</label>";
                echo"<input class='BizEditItemInput' type='number' id='BizEditItemPercent' name='BizEditItemPercent' step='any' min=0 value=\"$discountpercent\">%";
                echo"<span></span>";
            echo"</div>";
        echo"</div>";

        echo"<div class='BizEditItemDetails'>";
            echo"<div class='BizEdititemDiscountDetails'>";
                echo"<label for='BizEditItemDiscountPrice'>Discounted Price:</label>";
                echo"<input class='BizEditItemInput' type='number' id='BizEditItemDiscountPrice' name='BizEditItemDiscountPrice' step='any' min=0 value=\"$discountprice\" readonly >";
                echo"<span></span>";
            echo"</div>";
        echo"</div>";

        echo"<div class='BizEditItemDetails'>";
                echo"<label for='BizEditItemQty'>Quantity:</label>";
                echo"<input class='BizEditItemInput' type='number' id='BizEditItemQty' name='BizEditItemQty' min=0 value=\"$qty\">";
                echo"<span></span>";
        echo"</div>";



        echo"<div class='BizEditItemDetails'>";
            echo"<label for='BizEditItemDesc'>Desc:</label>";
            echo"<textarea class='BizEditItemInput' id='BizEditItemDesc' name='BizEditItemDesc' cols='30' rows='5'>$desc</textarea>";
            echo"<span></span>";
        echo"</div>";

        echo"<div class='BizEditItemDetails'>";
            echo"<input class='BizEditItemInput' style='margin-left:360px' type='submit' name='BizEditItemSubmit' value='Submit'>";
        echo"</div>";
```

Comment: delegate event to closest static container or document/body level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/on/

You need to change your jquery code to:

```
$(document).on('click','#BizEditItemRadioYes' ,function(){

    $('.BizEdititemDiscountDetails').show();

});
```

Replace Document with a container which is not dynamic.